# MVC 3/EF repository pattern and proper data access

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, repository, disconnected-environment

Being rather new to MVC 3 and EF, I'm trying to understand the best architectural approach to developing an application for my company. The application will be a large-scale application that potentially handles hundreds of users at the same time, so I want to make sure I understand and am following proper procedures. So far, I've determined that a simple repository pattern (such as Controller -> Repository -> EF) approach is the best and easiest to implement, but I'm not sure if that is definitely the best way to do things. The application will basically return data that is shown to a user in a devexpress grid and they can modify this data/add to it etc.

I found this article and it is rather confusing for me at this time, so I'm wondering if there is any reason to attempt to work with a disconnected EF and why you would even want to do so: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81543/Finally-Entity-Framework-working-in-fully-disconne?msg=3717432#xx3717432xx

So to summarize my question(s):

- Is the code below acceptable?
- Should it work fine for a large-scale MVC application?
- Is there a better way?
- Will unnecessary connections to SQL remain open from EF? (SQL Profiler makes it look like it stays open a while even after the using statement has exited)
- Is the disconnected framework idea a better one and why would you even want to do that? I don't believe we'll need to track data across tiers ...

**Note:** The repository implements IDisposable and has the dispose method listed below. It creates a new instance of the entity context in the repository constructor.

**Example Usage:**

**Controller** (LogOn using Custom Membership Provider):

```
if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
{
    User newUser = new User();                    

    using (AccountRepository repo = new AccountRepository())
    {
         newUser = repo.GetUser(model.UserName);
         ...
    }
}
```

**Membership Provider ValidateUser:**

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    using (AccountRepository repo = new AccountRepository())
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password.Trim()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(username.Trim()))
                return false;

            string hash = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password.Trim(), "md5");

            bool exists = false;

            exists = repo.UserExists(username, hash);

            return exists;
        }catch{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Account Repository Methods for GetUser & UserExists:**

**Get User:**

```
public User GetUser(string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            return entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(user => user.UserName == userName);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occurred: " + Ex.Message);
        }           
    }
```

**User Exists:**

```
 public bool UserExists(string userName, string userPassword)
 {
        if (userName == "" || userPassword == "")
            throw new ArgumentException(InvalidUsernamePassword);

        try
        {
            bool exists = (entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName && u.Password == userPassword) != null);
            return exists;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("An error occurred: " + Ex.Message);
        } 
    }
```

**Repository Snippets (Constructor, Dispose etc):**

```
    public class AccountRepository : IDisposable
    {
         private DbContext entities;

         public AccountRepository()
         {
            entities = new DbContext();
         }

         ...

         public void Dispose()
         {
            entities.Dispose();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's acceptable is pretty subjective, but if you want to do proper data access I suggest you do **NOT** use the repository pattern, as it breaks down as your application gets more complex.

The biggest reason is minimizing database access.  So for example look at your repository and notice the `GetUser()` method.  Now take a step back from the code and think about how your application is going to be used.  Now think about how often you are going to request data from the user table without any additional data.  The answer is almost always going to be "rarely" unless you are creating a basic data entry application.

You say it your application will show a lot of grids.  What data is in that Grid?  I'm assuming (without knowing your application domain) that the grids will combine user data with other information that's relevant for that user.  If that's the case, how do you do it with your repositories?

One way is to call on each repository's method individually, like so:

```
var user = userRepository.GetUser("KallDrexx");
var companies = companyRepository.GetCompaniesForUser(user.Id);
```

This now means you have 2 database calls for what really should be just one.  As your screens get more and more complex, this will cause the number of database hits to increase and increase, and if your application gets significant traffic this will cause performance issues.  The only real way to do this in the repository pattern is to add special methods to your repositories to do that specific query, like:

```
public class UserRepository
{
    public User GetUser(string userName)
    {
        // GetUser code          
    }

    public User GetUserWithCompanies(string userName)
    {
        // query code here
    }
}
```

So now what happens if you need users and say their contact data in one query.  Now you have to add another method to your user repository.  Now say you need to do another query that also returns the number of clients each company has, so you need to add yet another method (or add an optional parameter).  Now say you want to add a query that returns all companies and what users they contain.  Now you need a new query method but then comes the question of do you put that in the `User` repository or the `Company` repository?  How do you keep track of which one it's in and make it simple to choose between `GetUserWithCompany` and `GetCompanyWithUsers` when you need it later?

Everything gets very complex from that point on, and it's those situations that have made me drop the repository pattern.  What I do now for data access is I create individual query and command classes, each class represents 1 (and only 1) query or data update command to the database.  Each query class returns a view model that only contains the data I need for one specific user usage scenario. There are other data access patterns that will work too (specification pattern, some good devs even say you should just do your data access in your controllers since EF *is* your data access layer).

The key to doing data access successfully is good planning.  Do you know what your screens are going to look like?  Do you know how users are going to use your system?  Do you know all the data that is actually going to be on each screen?  If the answer to any of these is no, then you need to take a step back and forget about the data layer, because the data layer is (or should be for a good application) determined based on how the application is actually going to be used, the UI and the screens should not be dependent on how the data layer was designed.  If you don't take your UI needs and user usage scenarios into account when developing the data access, your application will not scale well and will not be performant.  Sometimes that's not an issue if you don't plan on your site being big, but it never hurts to keep those things in mind.

Comment: Thank you KallDrexx for the excellent post. Do you have any examples or links you could provide of how you manage individual query and command classes?

Comment: I personally use an interface sort of how I outline in http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/viewmodel-based-data-access-layer-optionally-consolidated-query-classes/ (I've evolved it a bit from that post, but that's the basic idea).  Ayende has a good post on query objects at http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton.  It ultimately comes down to trying to find the way that you feel most comfortable with, and that only comes by trying different methods out and seeing what works best for you.

Comment: Also I'll add that one thing I've learned is that in regards to architecture pattern design, everyone preaches their preference as gospel but nothing should be taken as such.  Everyone says that their way "is the best"(tm) but there is no 100% way to do this (every pattern has its flaws) and it's really up to you to figure out what works best for you, your product, and your team (if you have one)

Comment: Thanks for the help! - One last thing if you don't mind - Why would you want to work with a disconnected framework like the link I provided in the question? This is certainly confusing to me! :)

Comment: The disconnected layers means that I don't have to change MVC controller code just because I need to re-organize my data access.  For example, if I notice I have 12 areas in my application that require different queries about user questions, I might move each of those query methods out of the UserQueries class and into a UserQuestionQueries class.  With the disconnected model, it allows me to change the grouping and my MVC controller code will still work perfectly without modification.

Comment: It also means I can change the architecture of my data layer (one class per query) without having to change anything on the MVC layer.  It does has it's flaws (it's a tiny tiny bit harder to find exactly where a query is actually implemented) but I have found ways to minimize that in my personal workflow so to make it an acceptable tradeoff to me.

Comment: Gotcha - I will read through your posts, blog post and Ayende's post to try to get a grasp on it. These concepts are a little advanced for me currently so I'm trying to wrap my head around them. Haven't had to do much work with EF or MVC before :)

Comment: No worries :).  If you are just getting started I suggest starting the easy way and putting your EF code right in your MVC controllers.  That will help you learn MVC and EF the fastest, and once you get the hang of it you can then branch out and try different data layer architectures.  That would be my personal approach.

Comment: Alright - thank you again. Excellent help and I'm sure it will be very beneficial!

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you do, you may consider moving instantiation and disposing of your context to your controller like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private Entities context = new Entities();

    ...

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You can then pass that context into any method that needs it without duplicating the overhead of creating it.

I disagree that the repository pattern is necessarily bad for the same reason.  You create multiple classes to break up your code to make it manageable and still reuse the same context. That could look something like this:

```
repository.Users.GetUser(userName);
```

In this case "Users" is a lazy loaded instance of your user repository class which reuses the context from your repository.  So the code for that Users property in your repository would look something like this:

```
private UserRepository users;

public UserRepository Users
{
    get
    {
        If (users == null)
        {
            users = new UserRepository(this);
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

You can then expose your context to these other lazy loaded  classes via a property.

I don't think this necessarily conflicts with KallDrexx's pattern.  His method simply flips this so instead of

```
repository.Users.GetUser(userName);
```

You would have something like

```
UserQuery query = new UserQuery(repository.Users);
```

This then becomes an issue of syntax. Do you want this:

```
repository.Area.Query(value1, value2, ...);
```

Or this:

```
AreaQuery query = new AreaQuery { Property1 = value1, ... };
```

The latter actually works nicer with model binding but obviously is more verbose when you actually have to code it.

Best advice KallDrexx gave is to just put your code I your actions and then figure it out.  If you are doing simple CRUD, then let MVC instantiate and populate your model, then all you have to do is attach and save.  If you find you can reuse code, move it to where it can be reused. If your application starts getting too complicated, try some of these recommendations until you find what works for you.